# Build and modify hadoop 2.5.0 source code using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, build-process, development-environment

I'm trying to build and modify hadoop 2.5.0 source code using eclipse.

I've followed all instructions in this tutorial 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-hadoop-contributions/
and this one too http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute.

But still I don't understand, how to build and test my modification directly from eclipse?

or if there is no way to do that, what is the best way to achive my goal to modify, build, and run my own modified version of hadoop?

Note: 
*I've already successfully build hadoop using maven via ubuntu terminal previously, and run the package successfully also.

*I'm new in java, eclipse, and hadoop development

Thanks.